# Ruby on Rails: undefined method for self action in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I'm getting an undefined method for `text_search`, but I have the method in my model, am I doing it wrong?

**searches_controller.rb**

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @lists = List.text_search(params[:query])
  end
end
```

**search.rb**

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.text_search(query)
    if query.present?
      where("name @@ :q or description @@ :q", q: query)
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
end
```

However, I'm still getting undefined method. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `Search` not `List`

```
@lists = Search.text_search(params[:query])
```

Because you are using `class Search` in your search.rb